# Trying to animate the camera in Blender 2.8

Tags: camera

I tried moving the camera around by using keyframes in Blender 2.8 for the camera to move from one location to another. But when I tried to play the animation, the camera doesn't seem to move at all, and I don't know how to fix this.

Does anyone know how I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: Probably you set the keyframes incorrectly by accident. Make sure you set the start and end keyframes at different frames. (And make sure the location is still correct directly before setting the keyframe) Maybe otherwise upload your .blend to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and add the link to your question.

Answer (score 4):

If your playhead is at the beginning of the timeline with the camera selected, then do the following:

1. Move the camera where you want to start (press <kbd>0</kbd> to look through it)
2. Insert a keyframe (press <kbd>I</kbd>)
3. Move the playhead on the timeline
4. Move the camera to a new spot
5. Insert another keyframe (press <kbd>I</kbd>)

...etc

Comment: I tried doing this, but it doesn't seem to work somehow.

Comment: I'm doing this in Blender 2.8, and I don't know how to navigate around with keyframes in this interface version.

Comment: @DavidLin this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zp6kCe5Kmf4) was a pretty good tutorial for animating in Blender 2.8. I know you're moving the camera, but his explanation of keyframing in general is really good.

Answer (score 1):

After creating the keyframes for the camera position, you need to open the camera properties, open the Motion Paths section, and click the "Calculate" button.

Then your camera will move as you want! Enjoy.